# Mongoose how to return all collection data after deleting one item

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I create a delete api and it works to delete the item in mongoose atlas, but it has 404 error when I add `profile.save()` to get all current items.

Node.js code:

```
router.delete('/delete/:id',(req, res) => {
    Profile.findOneAndDelete({_id:req.params.id}).then(profile => {

      // res.json(profile) this line works to return the deleted item but I want to use below line to return all data.

       profile.save().then(profiles => res.json(profiles)).catch(err=>res.status(404).json(err))
    })
.catch(err => res.status(404).json(err))
})
```

Result:

```
{
"result": {
    "$where": {
        "_id": "61e7b297f880e56c8f6f6b2e"
    },
    "matchedCount": 0
},
"numAffected": 0,
"filter": {
    "_id": "61e7b297f880e56c8f6f6b2e"
},
"query": {
    "_id": "61e7b297f880e56c8f6f6b2e"
}
}
```

I noticed that in some tutorials it worked when adding that line, but in my case it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `find` query to return all data. `save` function is used to update or `save` item to DB.

> The save() method returns a promise. If save() succeeds, the promise
> resolves to the document that was saved.

When you delete the document, it returns the deleted user only. If you want to save it again, you need to create a model and put the values there and call the save function.

> I add profile.save() to get all current items.
> It only returns the saved documents, it won't return you all the documents from the collection.

If you want to get all the profile data, call `find` query.

```
router.delete('/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const deletedProfile = await Profile.findOneAndDelete({_id:req.params.id}); // conatins only deleted profile
    const getAllProfile = await Profile.find({}); // get all profile
    // now you can return all the profiles 
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json(error);
  }    
 })
```

Comment: It is strange that I type the codes based on a video tutorial and in that video it works using save()...Thank you.